# Azure Logic Apps + SAP : Can't send an iDoc with the connector

Tags: azure-logic-apps, sap-dotnet-connector, idoc

I am creating a proof-of-concept with Logic Apps for my company but I am unable to use the SAP connector in order to send an iDoc.

SAP is on-premise so I installed on a VM both the SAP Connector 3.0 the Azure Gateway. It works fine : I tried from Logic Apps a simple RFC successfully and when choosing an iDoc I can retrieve all our custom iDocs.

But I cannot send an iDoc to the system.
Below is my exemple (edited after 's answer) :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Send xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740/Send">
    <idocData>
        <EDI_DC40  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740"  SEGMENT="1">
            <TABNAM  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
            <MANDT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">100</MANDT>
            <DOCNUM xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">0900000000000032</DOCNUM>
            <DOCREL xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">740</DOCREL>
            <STATUS xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">03</STATUS>
            <DIRECT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">1</DIRECT>
            <OUTMOD xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">2</OUTMOD>
            <IDOCTYP xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">ZSAF_ORD</IDOCTYP>
            <MESTYP xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">ZSAF_ORD</MESTYP>
            <SNDPOR xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">SNDPOR</SNDPOR>
            <SNDPRT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">LS</SNDPRT>
            <SNDPRN xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">LGCAPPTEST</SNDPRN>
            <RCVPOR xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">RCVPOR</RCVPOR>
            <RCVPRT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">LS</RCVPRT>
            <RCVPRN xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">RCVPRN</RCVPRN>
            <CREDAT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">20180226</CREDAT>
            <CRETIM xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">110000</CRETIM>
            <SERIAL xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">20180226110000</SERIAL>
        </EDI_DC40>
        <Z1ZTREFRTE xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
            <RTCODFLU xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >SHPFIR</RTCODFLU>
            <RTCRINU1 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >zzzzzzz</RTCRINU1>
            <RTCRINU4 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >CH00</RTCRINU4>
            <RTCRINU5 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >zzzzzzz</RTCRINU5>
            <RTCODSIT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >106</RTCODSIT>
            <RTLIBRTE xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >Libellé</RTLIBRTE>
            <RTDIRERR xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >/usr/sap/trans/user/echange/tmp/sap/</RTDIRERR>
            <VKORG xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >1000</VKORG>
            <VTWEG xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >01</VTWEG>
            <SPART xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >01</SPART>
            <AUART xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >ZO10</AUART>
            <PSTYV_AT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >ZTAX</PSTYV_AT>
            <MAIL xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >it-support@zzzzzzz.com</MAIL>
            <FONCTIONWAS xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" />
            <RTDIRMAINWAS xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" />
            <RTOLD xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" />
        </Z1ZTREFRTE>
        <Z1HEADERFIR xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740"  SEGMENT="1">
            <SENDERID xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >zzzzzzz</SENDERID>
            <SENDERSITE xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >CH00</SENDERSITE>
            <RECEIVERID xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >zzzzzzz SA (FIRSA)</RECEIVERID>
            <RECEIVERSITE xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >0000702557</RECEIVERSITE>
        </Z1HEADERFIR>
        <Z1ORDER_HEADER xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740"  SEGMENT="1">
            <BSTNR xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >LOGICAPPS-032</BSTNR>
            <BSTDK xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >20180226</BSTDK>
            <AUART xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >ZO10</AUART>
            <VKORG xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >1000</VKORG>
            <VTWEG xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >01</VTWEG>
            <SPART xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >01</SPART>
            <MBDAT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >00000000</MBDAT>
            <ETDAT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >20180226</ETDAT>
            <EZEIT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >090000</EZEIT>
            <MHR xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >210000</MHR>
            <INCO1 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >DDP</INCO1>
            <INCO2 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >zzzzzzz LES BAINS</INCO2>
            <ZBRGEWM3 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >0</ZBRGEWM3>
            <ZBRGEWMP xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >0</ZBRGEWMP>
            <ZBRGEWPL xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >0</ZBRGEWPL>
            <ZZBRGEWT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >0</ZZBRGEWT>
            <ZZDATENL xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >20180226</ZZDATENL>
            <RTCODFLU xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >SHPFIR</RTCODFLU>
            <SNDID xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >zzzzzzz</SNDID>
            <SSITE xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >CH00</SSITE>
            <RID xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >zzzzzzz</RID>
            <RSITE xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >1000</RSITE>
            <FILENAME xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" />
            <FDATE xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >20180201</FDATE>
            <FTIME xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >151839</FTIME>
            <ZSAFGUID xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >00000000000000000000000000000000</ZSAFGUID>
            <Z1EDITEXTH xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740"  SEGMENT="1">
                <TDID xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >Z094</TDID>
                <TSSPRAS xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >FR</TSSPRAS>
                <TDFORMAT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >*</TDFORMAT>
                <TDLINE xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >Ligne 1</TDLINE>
            </Z1EDITEXTH>
            <Z1EDITEXTH xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740"  SEGMENT="1">
                <TDID xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >Z094</TDID>
                <TSSPRAS xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >FR</TSSPRAS>
                <TDFORMAT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >*</TDFORMAT>
                <TDLINE xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >Ligne 2</TDLINE>
            </Z1EDITEXTH>
        </Z1ORDER_HEADER>
        <Z1EDI_POSTE  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >000010</POSNR>
            <ZZODN xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >0085085941</ZZODN>
            <ZZORD xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >274352</ZZORD>
            <ZZBATCH xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >1003715712</ZZBATCH>
            <ZZLAENG xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >0.000</ZZLAENG>
            <ZZBREIT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >0.000</ZZBREIT>
            <ZZHOEHE xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >0.000</ZZHOEHE>
            <ZZVOLUM xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >0.000</ZZVOLUM>
            <ZZMAKTX xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >274352</ZZMAKTX>
            <ZZMAKTX1 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >Liquids Perfume</ZZMAKTX1>
            <ZZBRGEW xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >252.900</ZZBRGEW>
            <ZZBRGEWU xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >KGM</ZZBRGEWU>
            <ZZNETGR xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >225.000</ZZNETGR>
            <ZZVHARTEXT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >D04</ZZVHARTEXT>
            <ZZNBEMB xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >9</ZZNBEMB>
            <ZZWAERS xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >EUR</ZZWAERS>
            <ZZVALDOUA xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >3172.50</ZZVALDOUA>
            <ZZORI xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >CH</ZZORI>
            <ZZPROV xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >CH</ZZPROV>
            <ZZDEST xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >FR</ZZDEST>
            <ZZVOLEHFILE xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >MTQ</ZZVOLEHFILE>
            <ZZBRGEWUFILE xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >KGM</ZZBRGEWUFILE>
            <ZZNETGRUFILE xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >KGM</ZZNETGRUFILE>
            <Z1ADRITEM  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
                <NBCOL xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >9</NBCOL>
                <ADRNETGR xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >225</ADRNETGR>
                <ZZBRGEWU xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >KGM</ZZBRGEWU>
                <ZZVOLEH xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >MTQ</ZZVOLEH>
                <ZZREGL xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >ADR</ZZREGL>
                <ZZUN xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >3082</ZZUN>
                <ZZGRPEMB xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >III</ZZGRPEMB>
                <ZZDESCTMD xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >JOLI ADR (AVEC ESPACES, et VIRGULES)</ZZDESCTMD>
                <CODE_PACK xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >D04</CODE_PACK>
            </Z1ADRITEM>
        </Z1EDI_POSTE>
        <E1EDKA1  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
            <PARVW xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >AG</PARVW>
            <NAME1 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >CH00</NAME1>
        </E1EDKA1>
        <E1EDKA1  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
            <PARVW xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >ZA</PARVW>
            <PARTN xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >CH00</PARTN>
            <NAME1 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >zzzzzzz zzzzzzz</NAME1>
            <STRAS xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >Rue De La Bergère7</STRAS>
            <ORT01 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >zzzzzzz</ORT01>
            <PSTLZ xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >1217</PSTLZ>
            <LAND1 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >CH</LAND1>
        </E1EDKA1>
        <E1EDKA1  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
            <PARVW xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >WE</PARVW>
            <PARTN xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >0900004230</PARTN>
            <NAME1 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >ROVAL</NAME1>
            <STRAS xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >ROUTE DE VIRE</STRAS>
            <STRS2 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >USINE DU zzzzzzz</STRS2>
            <ORT01 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >FLERS</ORT01>
            <PSTLZ xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >61100</PSTLZ>
            <LAND1 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >FR</LAND1>
        </E1EDKA1>
        <E1EDKA1  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
            <PARVW xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >ZC</PARVW>
            <PARTN xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >0900004230</PARTN>
            <NAME1 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >ROVAL</NAME1>
            <STRAS xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >ROUTE DE VIRE</STRAS>
            <STRS2 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >USINE DU zzzzzzz</STRS2>
            <ORT01 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >FLERS</ORT01>
            <PSTLZ xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >61100</PSTLZ>
            <LAND1 xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >FR</LAND1>
        </E1EDKA1>
        <Z1DELIVERY  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
            <NUMBER xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >0085085941</NUMBER>
            <Z1DELIVERYITEM xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
                <LINEITEM xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >900001</LINEITEM>
                <MATERIALNUMBER xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >274352</MATERIALNUMBER>
                <BATCHNUMBER xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >1003677826</BATCHNUMBER>
            </Z1DELIVERYITEM>
            <Z1DELIVERYITEM xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
                <LINEITEM xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >900002</LINEITEM>
                <MATERIALNUMBER xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >274352</MATERIALNUMBER>
                <BATCHNUMBER xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" >1003715712</BATCHNUMBER>
            </Z1DELIVERYITEM>
        </Z1DELIVERY>
   </idocData>
</Send>
```

I get this generic error from the Logic App connector :

> {
>     "status": 400,
>     "message": "Failed to process request. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
>     "source": "sapapplicationserver-logic-cp-westeurope.logic-ase-westeurope.p.azurewebsites.net"
>   }

Our SAP Team has no idea why it does not work.
**The previous exemple works fine if I use the HTTP Post on the server (/sap/bc/idoc_xml).**

I suppose there is something to add or change to the xml, but I don't know what exactly...

Comment: That doesn't look even similar to any error that would come from the on-prem bits.  I would focus on the Azure side.  SAP's probably working fine.

Comment: I do think SAP server is working fine, my guess is the SAP NCo 3. But, if RFC is ok, what on Azure would cause that ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code is working for me

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Send xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740/Send">
    <idocData>
        <EDI_DC40  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740"  SEGMENT="1">
            <TABNAM  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
            <MANDT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">100</MANDT>
            <DOCNUM xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">0900000000000032</DOCNUM>
            <DOCREL xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">740</DOCREL>
            <STATUS xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">03</STATUS>
            <DIRECT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">1</DIRECT>
            <OUTMOD xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">2</OUTMOD>
            <IDOCTYP xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">ZSAF_ORD</IDOCTYP>
            <MESTYP xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">ZSAF_ORD</MESTYP>
            <SNDPOR xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">SNDPOR</SNDPOR>
            <SNDPRT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">LS</SNDPRT>
            <SNDPRN xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">LGCAPPTEST</SNDPRN>
            <RCVPOR xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">RCVPOR</RCVPOR>
            <RCVPRT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">LS</RCVPRT>
            <RCVPRN xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">RCVPRN</RCVPRN>
            <CREDAT xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">20180226</CREDAT>
            <CRETIM xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">110000</CRETIM>
            <SERIAL xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/">20180226110000</SERIAL>
        </EDI_DC40>
        <Z1ZTREFRTE xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
            <RTCODFLU>SHPFIR</RTCODFLU>
            <RTCRINU1>zzzzzzz</RTCRINU1>
            <RTCRINU4>CH00</RTCRINU4>
            <RTCRINU5>zzzzzzz</RTCRINU5>
            <RTCODSIT>106</RTCODSIT>
            <RTLIBRTE>Libellé</RTLIBRTE>
            <RTDIRERR>/usr/sap/trans/user/echange/tmp/sap/</RTDIRERR>
            <VKORG>1000</VKORG>
            <VTWEG>01</VTWEG>
            <SPART>01</SPART>
            <AUART>ZO10</AUART>
            <PSTYV_AT>ZTAX</PSTYV_AT>
            <MAIL >it-support@zzzzzzz.com</MAIL>
            <FONCTIONWAS  />
            <RTDIRMAINWAS  />
            <RTOLD/>
        </Z1ZTREFRTE>
        <Z1HEADERFIR xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740"  SEGMENT="1">
            <SENDERID>zzzzzzz</SENDERID>
            <SENDERSITE>CH00</SENDERSITE>
            <RECEIVERID>zzzzzzz SA (FIRSA)</RECEIVERID>
            <RECEIVERSITE>0000702557</RECEIVERSITE>
        </Z1HEADERFIR>
        <Z1ORDER_HEADER xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740"  SEGMENT="1">
            <BSTNR>LOGICAPPS-032</BSTNR>
            <BSTDK>20180226</BSTDK>
            <AUART>ZO10</AUART>
            <VKORG>1000</VKORG>
            <VTWEG>01</VTWEG>
            <SPART>01</SPART>
            <MBDAT>00000000</MBDAT>
            <ETDAT>20180226</ETDAT>
            <EZEIT>090000</EZEIT>
            <MHR>210000</MHR>
            <INCO1>DDP</INCO1>
            <INCO2>zzzzzzz LES BAINS</INCO2>
            <ZBRGEWM3>0</ZBRGEWM3>
            <ZBRGEWMP>0</ZBRGEWMP>
            <ZBRGEWPL>0</ZBRGEWPL>
            <ZZBRGEWT>0</ZZBRGEWT>
            <ZZDATENL>20180226</ZZDATENL>
            <RTCODFLU>SHPFIR</RTCODFLU>
            <SNDID>zzzzzzz</SNDID>
            <SSITE>CH00</SSITE>
            <RID>zzzzzzz</RID>
            <RSITE>1000</RSITE>
            <FILENAME/>
            <FDATE>20180201</FDATE>
            <FTIME>151839</FTIME>
            <ZSAFGUID>00000000000000000000000000000000</ZSAFGUID>
            <Z1EDITEXTH   SEGMENT="1">
                <TDID>Z094</TDID>
                <TSSPRAS>FR</TSSPRAS>
                <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
                <TDLINE>Ligne 1</TDLINE>
            </Z1EDITEXTH>
            <Z1EDITEXTH   SEGMENT="1">
                <TDID>Z094</TDID>
                <TSSPRAS>FR</TSSPRAS>
                <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
                <TDLINE>Ligne 2</TDLINE>
            </Z1EDITEXTH>
        </Z1ORDER_HEADER>
        <Z1EDI_POSTE  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
            <ZZODN>0085085941</ZZODN>
            <ZZORD>274352</ZZORD>
            <ZZBATCH>1003715712</ZZBATCH>
            <ZZLAENG>0.000</ZZLAENG>
            <ZZBREIT>0.000</ZZBREIT>
            <ZZHOEHE>0.000</ZZHOEHE>
            <ZZVOLUM>0.000</ZZVOLUM>
            <ZZMAKTX>274352</ZZMAKTX>
            <ZZMAKTX1>Liquids Perfume</ZZMAKTX1>
            <ZZBRGEW>252.900</ZZBRGEW>
            <ZZBRGEWU>KGM</ZZBRGEWU>
            <ZZNETGR>225.000</ZZNETGR>
            <ZZVHARTEXT>D04</ZZVHARTEXT>
            <ZZNBEMB>9</ZZNBEMB>
            <ZZWAERS>EUR</ZZWAERS>
            <ZZVALDOUA>3172.50</ZZVALDOUA>
            <ZZORI>CH</ZZORI>
            <ZZPROV>CH</ZZPROV>
            <ZZDEST>FR</ZZDEST>
            <ZZVOLEHFILE>MTQ</ZZVOLEHFILE>
            <ZZBRGEWUFILE>KGM</ZZBRGEWUFILE>
            <ZZNETGRUFILE>KGM</ZZNETGRUFILE>
            <Z1ADRITEM   SEGMENT="1">
                <NBCOL>9</NBCOL>
                <ADRNETGR>225</ADRNETGR>
                <ZZBRGEWU>KGM</ZZBRGEWU>
                <ZZVOLEH>MTQ</ZZVOLEH>
                <ZZREGL>ADR</ZZREGL>
                <ZZUN>3082</ZZUN>
                <ZZGRPEMB>III</ZZGRPEMB>
                <ZZDESCTMD>JOLI ADR (AVEC ESPACES, et VIRGULES)</ZZDESCTMD>
                <CODE_PACK>D04</CODE_PACK>
            </Z1ADRITEM>
        </Z1EDI_POSTE>
        <E1EDKA1  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
            <PARVW>AG</PARVW>
            <NAME1>CH00</NAME1>
        </E1EDKA1>
        <E1EDKA1  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
            <PARVW>ZA</PARVW>
            <PARTN>CH00</PARTN>
            <NAME1>zzzzzzz zzzzzzz</NAME1>
            <STRAS>Rue De La Bergère7</STRAS>
            <ORT01>zzzzzzz</ORT01>
            <PSTLZ>1217</PSTLZ>
            <LAND1>CH</LAND1>
        </E1EDKA1>
        <E1EDKA1  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
            <PARVW>WE</PARVW>
            <PARTN>0900004230</PARTN>
            <NAME1>ROVAL</NAME1>
            <STRAS>ROUTE DE VIRE</STRAS>
            <STRS2>USINE DU zzzzzzz</STRS2>
            <ORT01>FLERS</ORT01>
            <PSTLZ>61100</PSTLZ>
            <LAND1>FR</LAND1>
        </E1EDKA1>
        <E1EDKA1  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
            <PARVW>ZC</PARVW>
            <PARTN>0900004230</PARTN>
            <NAME1>ROVAL</NAME1>
            <STRAS>ROUTE DE VIRE</STRAS>
            <STRS2>USINE DU zzzzzzz</STRS2>
            <ORT01>FLERS</ORT01>
            <PSTLZ>61100</PSTLZ>
            <LAND1>FR</LAND1>
        </E1EDKA1>
        <Z1DELIVERY  xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ZSAF_ORD//740" SEGMENT="1">
            <NUMBER>0085085941</NUMBER>
            <Z1DELIVERYITEM SEGMENT="1">
                <LINEITEM>900001</LINEITEM>
                <MATERIALNUMBER>274352</MATERIALNUMBER>
                <BATCHNUMBER>1003677826</BATCHNUMBER>
            </Z1DELIVERYITEM>
            <Z1DELIVERYITEM SEGMENT="1">
                <LINEITEM>900002</LINEITEM>
                <MATERIALNUMBER>274352</MATERIALNUMBER>
                <BATCHNUMBER>1003715712</BATCHNUMBER>
            </Z1DELIVERYITEM>
        </Z1DELIVERY>
   </idocData>
</Send>
```

**custom segment name is not use as a xml tag name you need to pass latest version name of segment over here then it will be work else not**

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help. I edited my question with a full xml iDoc based on yours. Could you please have a look ? Again, thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for your edit but no, it is not working. Still the same error : Failed to process request. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.